# I can compile with SDL1.2 but not with SDL2 (C::B)

Tags: sdl, codeblocks

I've been learning **SDL** for a little time, and now I've decided to try out **SDL2**, mainly to try its hardware acceleration. But the problem is, I can't compile it at all, while the same code  compiled correctly with **SDL1.2**.

The sample code is:

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
int main( int argc, char *args[] )
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

With the original linker settings: `-lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL`
everything compiles.

But as soon as I change `#include "SDL/SDL.h"` to `#include "SDL2/SDL.h"`
and change linker settings to
`-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`
I get the errors:

```
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `SDL_main':|
main.cpp|5|undefined reference to `SDL_Init'|
main.cpp|8|undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'|
libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa7)||undefined reference to `WinMain@16'|
```

I've got **SDL1.2** installed in **C:/SDL-1.2.15** and **SDL2** installed in **C:/SDL2**

In search directories, I added both SDL1.2 and SDL2 Include and Lib folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work, but if you are using the "x86_64-w64-mingw32" folder, try using the other one (the one with i686) this helped me. I was having the EXACT same problem as you, and using literally, to the line, the same test code as you. I hope this helps.